# Varnish + Nginx proxy configuration on plesk

Tags: nginx, docker, varnish, plesk

I followed the official tuto for the Varnish via Docker configuration on plesk. https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-t...cker-container

i have a VPS Ubuntu with plesk and many domains.

I followed all steps : 
I created a domain test.monserveur.com
I use the Docker image million12/varnish
On the Docker container setting, the mapping redirect the 80 port to the 32780
On plesk for the hosting parameters, the option “SSL/TLS support” and “Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS” are deactivated
I deactived also the security mod for this domain
On the proxy rules of the docker container (/etc/varnish/default.vcl), i put fo the .host test.monserveur.com and .port 7080
On the function sub vcl_deliver, i put :

```
if (obj.hits > 0) {
set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
} else {
set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
}
```

I still have a 503 page with a MISS on the header for the page on test.monserveur.com

I can't understand where is the problem. I tried to put on the .host the serveur IP and with a link to another domain of the server. I think it's a problem with a setting but i don't know where.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

A 503 error response from Varnish means that your Docker container is not configured properly. You should check whether the container and Varnish within the container are running properly. Additionally, the configuration file must have valid syntax and the correct port and IP address of the server have to be set in the configuration file.

Without knowing what you've entered, I cannot give you a better advice! If you follow the tutorial completely, it will work. I've created over 10 working instances while I wrote the text!

PS: Please use the official Plesk forum with more information (also add your configuration file) if you still cannot solve your problem - https://talk.plesk.com/

Have success!